# ARRAYLIST FORMADO POR OBJETOS

Tags: arraylist, objeto

Tengo un `ArrayList<>` llamado `listaAlumnos`, en el cual almaceno diferentes objetos de una clase Alumno (nombre,dni,...), el problema es que necesitaría comprobar si existe o no un objeto dentro de ese `ArrayList` y si existe, eliminarlo

```
System.out.println("Introduce DNI");
String delete = sc.next();
for(int i = 0; i < listaAlumnos.size() ;i++) {
    listaAlumnos.get(i).getDni();
    if(listaAlumnos.contains(delete)) {
        listaAlumnos.remove(i);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("No existe");
}
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tu código funciona bien, solo que si el ArrayList almacena objetos de tipo Alumno, nunca podras obtenerlo mediante un texto, ejemplo:

```
if(listaAlumnos.contains(delete))
```

Lo correcto seria obtener el objeto Alumno y sacar el DNI de el, de la siguiente manera:

```
if(listaAlumno.get(i).getDni().equals(delete))
```

El `else` en cada vuelta del bucle, si el DNI del alumno no coincide imprimirá "No existe", no es cierto, no coincide en esa vuelta, quizás en la siguiente si.

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Introduce DNI: ");
    
String delete = scanner.nextLine();
    
for (int i = 0; i < listaAlumnos.size(); i++) {
    if(listaAlumnos.get(i).getDni().equals(delete)) {
        listaAlumnos.remove(i);
    }
}
    
scanner.close();
```

Para comprobar si se elimino puedes recorrer e imprimir la lista devuelta. Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias !!!!!!!! Al final luchando terminé con este código:

Comment: System.out.println("Introduce DNI");
      String delete = sc.next();
      String id = null;
      for(int i = 0; i < listaAlumnos.size() ;i++) {
       id = listaAlumnos.get(i).getDni();
       if(id.equals(delete)) {
        listaAlumnos.remove(i);
       }
      }

Comment: @AlbitaMari si la respuesta te fue útil, considera marcarla como respuesta aceptada